# HTACCESS Request wp-content directory using Query String

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am looking for a way to load the `wp-content` directory url to be served in a query string like
`wp-content/uploads?file=JohnDoe.jpg` as I am beginner in .htaccess

I checked the given snippet https://gist.github.com/hakre/1552239 but it seems to be working while the user is not logged in and thus redirecting to login page. I wonder there could be a solution to serve the file in a query string than to display the full url from wp-content/uploads directory and so I am also looking for a solution without make use of any plugin. File served should be visible to all and thus no login check should be there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want this, if you still want the files to be available to everyone? What is the point then even? I guess you could probably just remove the check for a logged-in user from line #16 of that code, but what for … total mystery.

Comment: I am looking for a solution where the user cannot download the video from any downloader as video downloader cannot interpret the query string according to me. An alternative is to use DRM License and that I am not aware of.

Comment: _“as video downloader cannot interpret the query string”_ - what gave you that absurd idea?

Comment: Do you know any alternative solution regarding this?